# Problem with plotting a list as a 3d scatter

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, 3d, scatter

I'm working with the following code, which simulates a random walk in 2 dimensions. The walkers positions are stored on a list of tuples:

```
# Comparação entre random walk e difusão em 1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

M = 100 # Número de walkers
L = 100 # Tamanho da malha

# A cada intervalo de tempo, mover o walker e propagar a difusão

p = 0.1 # Probabilidade de andar
pinv = 1.0-p
nsteps = 2001 # Número de intervalos de tempo

# Iniciando os walkers

x = np.zeros(M) # Posição inicial dos walkers no eixo x
Z = [(0,0) for i in range (M)]
edgesrw = np.array(range(-L,L+1))-0.5
xc = 0.5*(edgesrw[:-1]+edgesrw[1:])

#%%

def animate(it):
    global x
    x = get_data(Z, M)

    # Trajetória dos walkers nos eixos x e y
    if (np.mod(it,noutput)==0):
        plot.set_offsets(Z)
        ax.set_title('Tempo = {}'.format(it))
    return plot

def get_data(Z, M):
    # Atualizar a posição de todos os walkers
    for iw in range(M):
        rndx = random.random()
        dx = -1*(rndx<p)+1*(rndx>pinv)
        rndy = random.random()
        dy = -1*(rndy<p)+1*(rndy>pinv)
        x, y = Z[iw]
        Z[iw] = x+dx, y+dy
    return Z

plt.ion()
noutput = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(6, 6)
ax.set_xlim((-100, 100))
ax.set_ylim((-100, 100))
ax.set_xlabel('Distância percorrida (x)')
ax.set_ylabel('Distância percorrida (y)')
x = get_data(Z, M)
plot = ax.scatter (*zip(*Z), s = 1)
            
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = animate, frames = nsteps, interval = 50)
ani.save('randomwalk2d.gif')
plt.show()
```

After running it, I have this as a result:

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is expand this approach to 3 dimensions. I've added one more coordinate to each tuple and also added the random motion to the z axis, plus some other minor changes:

```
# Comparação entre random walk e difusão em 1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

M = 100 # Número de walkers
L = 100 # Tamanho da malha

# A cada intervalo de tempo, mover o walker e propagar a difusão

p = 0.1 # Probabilidade de andar
pinv = 1.0-p
nsteps = 2001 # Número de intervalos de tempo

# Iniciando os walkers

x = np.zeros(M) # Posição inicial dos walkers nos eixos x, y e z
Z = [(0,0,0) for i in range (M)]
edgesrw = np.array(range(-L,L+1))-0.5
xc = 0.5*(edgesrw[:-1]+edgesrw[1:])

#%%

def animate(it):
    global x
    x = get_data(Z, M)

    # Trajetória dos walkers nos eixos x, y e z
    if (np.mod(it,noutput)==0):
        plot.set_offsets(Z)
        ax.set_title('Tempo = {}'.format(it))
    return plot

def get_data(Z, M):
    # Atualizar a posição de todos os walkers
    for iw in range(M):
        rndx = random.random()
        dx = -1*(rndx<p)+1*(rndx>pinv)
        rndy = random.random()
        dy = -1*(rndy<p)+1*(rndy>pinv)
        rndz = random.random()
        dz = -1*(rndz<p)+1*(rndz>pinv)
        x, y, z = Z[iw]
        Z[iw] = x+dx, y+dy, z+dz
    return Z

plt.ion()
noutput = 5
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
fig.set_size_inches(6, 6)
ax.set_xlim((-100, 100))
ax.set_ylim((-100, 100))
ax.set_zlim((-100, 100))
ax.set_xlabel('Distância percorrida (x)')
ax.set_ylabel('Distância percorrida (y)')
ax.set_zlabel('Distância percorrida (z)')
x = get_data(Z, M)
plot = ax.scatter (*zip(*Z), s = 1, color = 'Blue')
            
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = animate, frames = nsteps, interval = 50)
ani.save('randomwalk3d.gif')
plt.show()
```

But when I run it, not a single walker leaves the origin:

[3d random walk attempt (failed)](https://i.imgur.com/GkkwV8A.mp4)

I know that the random walks are being calculated though, as I can check this through the console at the end of the simulation and the tuples are all over the place. I have tried multiple things I've seen on other questions here but nothing has worked so far and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're plotting `Z` in `ax.scatter (*zip(*Z), s = 1, color = 'Blue')`, but in `Z = [(0,0,0) for i in range (M)]` you've set `Z` to all zero 3-tuples. Maybe that's why?

Comment: The `Z = [(0,0,0) for i in range (M)]` is supposed to be the initial position, and I wanted to update it over time. For some reason it works in 2d but not in 3d